# Не выводит последний элемент (вне зависимости от количества)

Tags: python

```
marks1 = []
while True:
    n = list(input().strip().split(';'))
    for i in n:
        n = str(n)
        i.split()
        if i.isdigit():
            marks1.append(i)
    mathematics = int(marks1[0])
    physics = int(marks1[1])
    russian = int(marks1[2])
    line_av = (mathematics + physics + russian) / 3
    print(line_av)
    marks1 = []
```

p.s В предыдущем вопросе не весь код скинул. Пример ввода данных(Петров;85;92;78,переход на новую строку,Сидоров;100;88;94,переход на новую строку, Иванов;58;72;85 и т.д) вводить надо с новой строки каждый набор данных.
Мне надо вывести средний балл учеников, но проблема в том что средний бал последнего ученика никогда не выводиться. Хотя в дебагере я проверил все вроде правильно, и выводит как положено. Как исправить?

Comment: Вы удалили вопрос в процессе моей работы с ним. Совершенно неверно так делать - есть функция "Править". Да и невежливо.

Comment: Приношу свои искренние извинения, не обратил внимания на "Править".

Comment: Повторю коротко свой удалённый вопрос -  как может не выводиться "средний бал последнего ученика", если у вас бесконечный цикл? В нем принципиально нет никакого "последнего". Соответственно, у меня всё выводится.

Comment: Проблему обнаружил, надо было дольше мне подумать, прежде чем задавать глупый вопрос)

Comment: хоть напишите, что не так-то было?

Comment: надо было на enter нажать, и последний средний бал выводится

Comment: Не знаю почему не обратил внимания на консоль